# Exporting model from Blender to three.js CanvasRenderer weird distorded normals

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, three.js, blender

I'm trying to export a model using the Three.js [import export for blender](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender) and everything is working fine when I used the WebGLRenderer, but if I use CnavasRenderer (what I need for crossbrowsing support) I get a model but with a weird behavior (if I export a model with more than 2 geometries touching each other) with blinking and distorded normals from my mesh. I doesnt matter if I have tested joining the model before exporting into a single mesh and is the same, its like if there are 2 different geometries touching each other this happens)

I link a image from the model as an example!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATjLH.png

Someone have some tip to export this from blender to use with CanvasRenderer? I will appreciate any help :)

Thank you!!

Comment: 1. Can you show a live link to demonstrate the problem? 2. Why do you believe the normals are "distorted"?

Comment: Hi. Yes I post a [link](http://btobinteractive.com/test/ejemplo.mp4) to a video with the behaviour.

Comment: I thought the same, but I was not sure, I thought that maybe I did something wrong exporting the model from Blender, but I have tried every possibility with the same result...I'll report it and I'll comment with the answer in case I get something...

Comment: @elverde 1. Can you show a live link to demonstrate the problem (not a video)? 2. Why do you believe the normals are "distorted"?

Comment: @WestLangley You can check it [here](http://www.btobinteractive.com/test/) Answering your question 2, I dont know how to explain it, check it out the link and you could judge by yourself :)

Comment: What you are seeing is a limitation of `CanvasRenderer` due to how it handles depth sorting. There are no "distorted normals".

Comment: So then, its impossible to achieve that using CanvasRenderer? The only comment that I got from mrdoob is "You should considering stop using CanvasRenderer :)" haha

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a bit I found this alternative, I hope it helps if someone have the same problem.

To me, the solution was to use the [ThreeCSG library](https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG) to make substractions, unions, etc. I think that doesn't work for most cases because is a little bit messy to do that with a complex model, but it's ok in my case.

I leave you an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO8Gh.png) with the result, and the render using CanvasRenderer it works perfectly

Thank you!